# Android - Kotlin - How to iterate Group children elements

Tags: android, kotlin, grouping

I have several Spinners and TextViews which are grouped together in a `<android.support.constraint.Group>` tag.

How does one iterate the elements of the group?

I have tried

```
val ids = findViewById<Group>(R.id.group_lala).referencedIds
for (id in ids) {
        val frm = findViewById<*>(id)
    }
```

But I cannot have *

Comment: Can't you use `findViewById<View>`?

Comment: Ha! That I can indeed! I still forget about the View being general, not certain layout element type... If you want, put it as answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
val ids = findViewById<Group>(R.id.group_lala).referencedIds
for (id in ids) {
    val view = findViewById<View>(id)
}
```